# Подсветка кода в Visual studio 2017 работает с перебоями для #define-ов, прописанных во включаемых файлах

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, макросы, константа

Пишу программу на C++ с использованием WinSock2. Эта библиотека содержит ряд констант и макросов, созданных с помощью `#define`. Во время написания кода эти константы и макросы в случайные моменты времени то начинают нормально подсвечиваться, то перестают и подчёркиваются как неопределённые идентификаторы. Во втором случае, при наведении на подчёркнутый код (для примера возьму `SOCKET_ERROR`), появляется следующая подсказка среды разработки:

> `#define SOCKET_ERROR (-1)`
>
> идентификатор "SOCKET_ERROR" не определён

(Оба эти сообщения в составе одного окошка подсказки)

На мой взгляд, получается абсурд: среда разработки сама показывает мне определение константы и тут же говорит, что она этого определения не видит. Однако ещё раз подчёркиваю, что через некоторое время работы с кодом, абсолютно в случайный момент, синтаксис начинает подсвечиваться, как подобает, но позже, снова в случайный момент, ломается.

Вот так это выглядит:
[image: ошибочная подсветка]

Сведения о Visual Studio:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017  Версия 15.5.6
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.6+27130.2027 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Версия 4.7.03056
>
> Установленная версия: Professional
>
> Visual Basic 2017   00370-20007-73916-AA071 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2017
>
> Visual C# 2017   00370-20007-73916-AA071 Microsoft Visual C# 2017
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00370-20007-73916-AA071 Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
>
> Visual F# 4.1   00370-20007-73916-AA071 Microsoft Visual F# 4.1
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.31127.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   1.0 Provides languages services
>   for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.51007.0 Дополнительные
>   сведения см. на сайте https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.31106.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Azure Data Lake Node   1.0 This package contains the Data Lake
>   integration nodes for Server Explorer.
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Cookiecutter   3.0.17320.1 Предоставляет средства для поиска, создания
>   экземпляров и настройки шаблонов в формате cookiecutter.
>
> Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0 События диагностики Fabric
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> Merq   1.1.17-rc (cba4571) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager
>   for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.2.9000.1 HDInsight Node under
>   Azure Node
>
> Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.2.9000.1 Language
>   service for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.2.9000.1
>   Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0 Azure Stream Analytics
>   Node under Azure Node
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1 Develop, run,
>   validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5
>   your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL +
>   F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.8.4-pre (3fe64e3) Support for
>   debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> Python   3.0.17320.1 Предоставляет IntelliSense, проекты, шаблоны,
>   отладку, интерактивные окна и другие вспомогательные функции для
>   разработчиков Python.
>
> Python — поддержка IronPython   3.0.17320.1 Предоставляет шаблоны и
>   интеграцию для проектов на основе IronPython.
>
> Python — поддержка Django   3.0.17320.1 Предоставляет шаблоны и
>   интеграцию для веб-платформы Django.
>
> Python — поддержка профилирования   3.0.17320.1 Поддержка
>   профилирования для проектов Python.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61710.120 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0 Enables Visual Studio's testing
>   tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third
>   Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
>
> ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
>
> Visual C++ для кроссплатформенной разработки мобильных приложений
>   15.0.27005.02 Visual C++ для кроссплатформенной разработки мобильных приложений
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> WebJobs Tools v1.0.0   15.0.31106.0 WebJobs Tools v1.0.0
>
> Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0 Этот пакет содержит компоненты,
>   необходимые для интеграции Visual Studio со службой Workflow Manager.
>
> Xamarin   4.8.0.760 (fc93f3f5b) Расширение Visual Studio,
>   обеспечивающее разработку для Xamarin.iOS и Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.8.188 (c5813fa34) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.1.5.0 (HEAD/75f8c6838) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.6.1.4 (db807ec) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Адаптер теста для Google Test   1.0 Включает средства тестирования
>   Visual Studio и модульные тесты для Google Test.  Условия
>   использования и уведомления сторонних производителей см. в каталоге
>   установки расширения.
>
> Диспетчер пакетов NuGet   4.5.0 Диспетчер пакетов NuGet в Visual
>   Studio. Дополнительную информацию о NuGet см. на веб-сайте
>   http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> Инструменты Microsoft Azure   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools для Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2017 — v2.9.51120.3
>
> Инструменты Node.js   1.4.11025.7 Обеспечивает поддержку разработки и
>   отладки приложений Node.js в Visual Studio
>
> Инструменты R для Visual Studio   1.3.31108.1213 Предоставляет систему
>   проектов, интерактивное окно R, построение графиков и многое другое
>   для языка программирования R.
>
> Инструменты Visual Studio для Apache Cordova   15.123.6829.2
>   Инструменты Visual Studio для Apache Cordova
>
> Инструменты Visual Studio для CMake   1.0 Инструменты Visual Studio
>   для CMake
>
> Инструменты Visual Studio для Unity   3.5.0.3 Инструменты Visual
>   Studio для Unity
>
> Инструменты непрерывной поставки Microsoft для Visual Studio   0.3
>   Упрощение настройки непрерывной интеграции сборок и непрерывной
>   поставки сборок из среды Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Инструменты разработчика Office для Visual Studio 2017 — RUS
>   15.0.27005.00 Инструменты разработчика Microsoft Office для Visual Studio 2017 — RUS
>
> Мастера Microsoft Visual C++   1.0 Мастера Microsoft Visual C++
>
> Набор средств Visual Studio Tools для универсальных приложений для
>   Windows   15.0.27130.2020 Набор средств Visual Studio Tools для
>   универсальных приложений для Windows позволяет создавать универсальные
>   приложения, взаимодействие с которыми не будет различаться при работе
>   на любых устройствах с ОС Windows 10: телефонах, планшетах, ПК и
>   других. Набор средств включает пакет Microsoft Windows 10 SDK.
>
> Общие инструменты Windows Azure   1.10 Предоставляет общие службы для
>   использования мобильными службами и инструментами Microsoft Azure.
>
> Пакет VC Microsoft Visual Studio   1.0 Пакет VC Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>
> Пакет размещения адаптеров отладки Visual Studio Code   1.0 Уровень
>   взаимодействия для размещения адаптеров отладки Visual Studio Code в
>   Visual Studio
>
> Пакет средств Application Insights для Visual Studio   8.10.01106.1
>   Средства Application Insights для Visual Studio
>
> Разработка на Visual C++ для Linux   1.0.8 Разработка на Visual C++
>   для Linux
>
> Система проектов JavaScript UWP   2.0 Система проектов JavaScript UWP
>
> Средства Microsoft Azure Service Fabric для Visual Studio   2.0
>   Средства Microsoft Azure Service Fabric для Visual Studio
>
> Средства TypeScript   15.5.11025.1 Средства TypeScript для Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>
> Языковая служба JavaScript   2.0 Языковая служба JavaScript

Воспроизводимый (в некоторой степени) пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32

    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>


    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

    void sendToSocket(std::string message, SOCKET client_socket)
        {
            int sendingResultCode = send(client_socket, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
            if (sendingResultCode == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
                throw std::exception("Sending failed", errorCode);
            }
            else
                std::cout << sendingResultCode << " bytes sent\n";
        }
#endif
```

В приведённом выше примере `SOCKET_ERROR` подчёркнуто красным и всё происходит так, как описано в вопросе.

Вопрос: чем объяснить такое странное поведение и, самое главное, как его избежать?

P.S. На работу программы "испорченная" подсветка не влияет. Даже если все константы и макросы подчёркнуты красным, проект без проблем собирается и работает как нужно.

Comment: Постарайтесь пожалуйста, составить и приложить MCVE (минимальный воспроизводимый пример) (*MCVE is not defined by what it is, but rather what it should do: provide readers of the question with a clear example of your problem which leaves no room for guesswork*). Без него это во многом гадание на кофейной гуще. Также укажите точную версию IDE и какие плагины используются.

Comment: @Kromster Сделал, как Вы сказали

Comment: "*чем объяснить такое странное поведение*" - видимо, баг Visual Studio. Напишите в официальный форум поддержки: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html

Comment: скорее всего IntelliSense не компилирует код полностью, из соображений производительности, так что он вполне может ошибаться - показывать то, чего не видит полноценный компилятор, и наоборот

Comment: @PashaPash А нет ли каких-то настроек, позволяющих этого избежать?

Comment: @V-Mor если бы они были - их бы включили по умолчанию :)

Comment: @PashaPash Досадное упущение.

Comment: @V-Mor снесите папку .vs и переоткройте проект - с некоторой вероятностью поможет

Comment: @PashaPash У меня её и так нет

Comment: @V-Mor есть, просто она скрытая

Comment: @PashaPash Да, точно. Забыл что у меня не включён показ скрытых на этом компе.

Comment: @PashaPash И это-таки помогло! Вынесите в ответ и завтра, если ничего не изменится, я его приму (как Вы помните из вопроса, подсветка и так иногда появлялась, нужно проверить, не тот ли это случай)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97627/discussion-between-v-mor-and-pashapash).

Answer (score 0):

[@ PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash), вероятно, по своей скромности, не стал выносить это в ответ, однако отмечаю, что решение проблемы, представленное ниже, – полностью его заслуга.

Итак, чтобы стабилизировать подсветку констант и макросов, определённых с помощью `#define` во включённых файлах, необходимо было всего лишь **удалить скрытую папку `.vs` из каталога проекта**. Это полностью решило проблему – теперь все константы и макросы подсвечиваются как нужно.